# Android START_STICKY Service handle System kill

Tags: android, android-service

I have a Service which handles downloading a list of simple files which it receives via the intent upon creation. I stop the Service once all the items have been downloaded. However if the System decides to kill the Service, upon recreation (because of START_STICKY) I will receive a null intent (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#START_STICKY). Is there a way to continue on where the Service was stopped without having to manually persist the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flag START_REDELIVER_INTENT, which will call again the onStartCommand method of the service with the last sent intent if the service's process is killed before it calls stopSelf. Anyway I don't know how and what your service exactly does, so it could be that you still have to save in a persistent way some information.